# How to get the code of a Dynamics CRM online solution?

Tags: visual-studio, dynamics-crm, dynamic-programming, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

My case is the next one: We have a Dynamics CRM online 2016 with some solutions that a third party created and I need to bring the whole code of one solution, I need to see the code of all the plugins, workflows and Javascript files that the solution has.

I tried in Visual Studio creating a new Dynamics CRM project and then select "New Visual Studio Solution for Dynamics CRM". Then I connected to our Dynamics CRM server and I chose the solution that I wanted. The problem is that with these steps only brings me the structure of the solution with its plugins and workflow but it doesn't bring me the code (plugins and workflows code) that is what I actually wanted. I need to modify a plugin that is already done by the third party company.

I will appreciate if someone can help me with my question. I'm new in the community and any advice will be appreciate.

[New Dynamics CRM project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJuzb.png)

Answer (score 1):

Plugins are compiled and stored on the disk/database as dlls. So unless you own the source code, there is no way to achieve what you are trying to do.

What you can try doing though it to use a decompiler like dotpeek to extract the source if it is not obfuscated. You can then copy the source and make necessary changes, deploy the plugin and disable the other plugin.

Comment: in order to replace an assembly the signing must be the same, and because he doesn't have the source code (the .snk file) is not possible. He can of course create brand new plugins, uninstall the existing plugins and replace them with the new ones.

Comment: So If I want to modify an existing code and I don't have the code is there no way to modify that? How about if I want to compare one plugin in two instances to check if there are differences between plugins?

Comment: @GabyMarquez there is no way to modify the plugin you do not own, to compare the code between instances the only way to do that would be to export the solution out, extract it and you would have access to the compiled dll. If the solution is a managed solution and you do not have a copy of the solution, you are out of luck as you cannot export a managed solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered reaching out to the third party vendor?  They might be able to handle your issue a lot better than trying to extract the source through a complex method only to find out it still will take several days to understand their approach properly. You would think [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) would apply here.

Comment: managed or unmanaged solution doesn't make a difference in this scenario

Comment: You're right, I removed that part.. The rest of what I said is still valid.